# Sum elements of same index from different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have a list of lists, where each inner list represents a row in a spreadsheet.  With my current data structure, how can I perform an operation on each element on an inner list with the same index ( which amounts to basically performing operations down a column in a spreadsheet.)

Here is an example of what I am looking for (in terms of addition)

```
>>> lisolis = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

>>> sumindex = [1+4+7, 2+5+8, 3+6+9]

>>> sumindex = [12, 15, 18]
```

This problem can probably be solved with slicing, but I'm unable to see how to do that cleanly.  Is there a nifty tool/library out there that can accomplish this for me?

Comment: How about with numpy arrays : `np.array(lisolis).sum(0).tolist()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
sumindex = [sum(elts) for elts in zip(*lisolis)]
```

Comment: How would this change if I was unpacking this lists as values in a dictionary, rather than a list of lists?

Comment: That should just be `*my_dict.values()` instead of `*lisolis`.

Answer (score 1):

@tzaman has a good solution for lists, but since you have also put `numpy` in the tags, there's an even simpler solution if you have a numpy 2D array:

```
>>> inport numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> a.sum(axis=0)
array([12, 15, 18])
```

This should be faster if you have large arrays.

```
>>> sumindex = numpy.array(lisolis).sum(axis=0).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>import pandas as pd 
>>df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], columns=['A','B','C'])
>>df.sum()
A    12
B    15
C    18
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.

Answer (score 1):

The list(), map(), zip(), and sum() functions make short work of this problem:

```
>>> list(map(sum, zip(*lisolis)))
[12, 15, 18]
```

Comment: No need to use `list()`. `map(sum, zip(*lisolis))` is good enough.

Comment: @ComputerFellow This was a Python 3 question, so map() isn't good enough.  In Python 3, map() returns an iterator rather than a list.

Answer (score 1):

First I'll fill out the lists of what we want to add up:

```
>>> lisolis = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Then create an empty list for my sums:

```
>>> sumindex = []
```

Now I'll start a loop inside a loop. I'm going to add the numbers that are in same positions of each little list (that's the "y" loop) and I'm going to do that for each position (that's the "x" loop).

```
>>> for x in range(len(lisolis[0])):
        z = 0
        for y in range(len(lisolis)):
            z += lisolis[y][x]
    sumindex.append(z)
```

range(len(lisolis[0])) gives me the length of the little lists so I know how many positions there are to add up, and range(len(lisolis)) gives me the amount of little lists so I know how many numbers need to be added up for any particular position in the list.

"z" is a placecard holder. Each number in a particular list position is going to be added to "z" until they're summed up. After that, I'll put the value of "z" into the next slot in sumindex.

To see the results, I would then type:

```
>>>sumindex
```

which would give me:

```
 [12, 15, 18]
```